# Extracting vanishing points from the camera projection matrix

Tags: projective-geometry, computer-vision

I’m struggling with the following paragraph from the book Multiple View Geometry:

> The columns of the projective camera are 3-vectors which have a
>   geometric meaning as particular image points. With the notation that
>   the columns of $P$ are $\mathbf{p}_i$, $i=1,...,4$, then
>   $\mathbf{p}_1$, $\mathbf{p}_2$, $\mathbf{p}_3$ are the vanishing
>   points of the world coordinate X, Y and Z axes respectively. This
>   follows because these points are the images of the axes’ directions.

Can someone explain in more details why this is true? I know of vanishing points as the points where parallel lines meet when they’ve been transformed by a central projection but I don’t know how to go from that definition to the conclusion in this paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pieces that you need for understanding this are explained earlier in the book. It would be a good idea to review chapters 2 and 3 before proceeding further.

A point at infinity is the common intersection of a family of parallel lines. $P$ preserves intersections of lines, so its image is the vanishing point of the family.

The homogeneous coordinates of this point at infinity are just the *inhomogeneous* direction vector of the lines with a $0$ appended. So, for example, the point at infinity on the $X$-axis has homogeneous coordinates $\mathbf X_1=(1,0,0,0)^T$.Since the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors (multiply it out to see for yourself), $P\mathbf X_1 = \mathbf p_1$, and similarly for the other coordinate axes.